# Error while converting file into String in android

Tags: java, android, file

I have tried to convert a pdf file into string and upload it into my database using webservice.But Im getting Null pointer exception while i uploading pdf files.The below code works properly when i do the same process with an image file.Please give me a solution for this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 2) {
    try {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String  selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        convertFileToString(selectedImagePath);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No file found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here is my method to convert file into string.

```
public String convertFileToString(String pathOnSdCard){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pathOnSdCard+" is Uploading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String strFile=null;

    File file=new File(pathOnSdCard);

    try {

        byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);//Convert any file, image or video into byte array

        strFile = Base64.encodeToString(data,Base64.NO_WRAP);//Convert byte array into string
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FileBytes"+strFile,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       uploadFile(pathOnSdCard,strFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strFile;

}
```

Comment: where exactly is the issue occurring?

Comment: first check  both of your file_path and file are proper. they might throw nullpointer if any one of them not exist.

Comment: Which line throws the null pointer exception?

Comment: You cannot put a .pdf file in a String variable. So your subject is quite strange.

Comment: then what should i do now ? how to encode a pdf file?

Comment: private String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File file,String path){
        String encodedfile = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            String result = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            uploadFile(path,result);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } return encodedfile; }

Comment: Im getting memory out of bound exception while executing above code